# Confusion in aplay Command. 

Tags: linux, bluetooth, dbus, alsa

Here i want to understand this commmand.

```
aplay -D hw:0,0 /opt/WL1271_demo_01/gallery/Pop.wav
```

Why we used `asound.conf` file.

we have to need update bluetooth address of hands free device in this file to play audio in handsfree device?

Can anybody Explain me `aplay` command and how its works?

why we used here `-D hw:0,0` in this?

why we not used here `-Dplug:bluetooth hw:0,0` ?

==================================================================

Here is my /etc/asound.conf file

```
    pcm.!bluetooth {
    type bluetooth
    device 00:23:78:41:AB:9F
        playback_ports {
                0 alsa_pcm:playback_1
                1 alsa_pcm:playback_2
        }
        capture_ports {
                0 alsa_pcm:capture_1
                1 alsa_pcm:capture_2
        }

    }

pcm.!default {
    type plug
    slave.pcm bluetooth
    }


pcm.jack {
        type jack
        playback_ports {
                0 alsa_pcm:playback_1
                1 alsa_pcm:playback_2
        }
        capture_ports {
                0 alsa_pcm:capture_1
                1 alsa_pcm:capture_2
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are pointing `aplay` directly to some piece of hardware (`hw:0,1` – second output of the first sound device) instead of letting it use your `asound.conf` definition. Try this instead:

```
aplay -D bluetooth -c 2 -f S16_LE abc.wav
```

Please note, that if you are using the ALSA  interface this way anything else using that device (e.g. the Pulse Audio daemon) make this not work. You could probably use Pulse Audio instead of 'raw' ALSA, but I cannot help with that.

Update:

> why we used here `-D hw:0,0` in this?

How can we know? You provided the command. This means: use directly (this means: ignoring the aliases in `asound.conf` file) the first output of the first audio hardware (this usually means the output of your primary sound card).

> why we not used here -Dplug:bluetooth hw:0,0 ?

Because the '-D' option accepts a single parameter. This can be 'hw:0,0', this can be 'plug:bluetooth', this can be any alias defined in the `asound.conf` file (like 'jack' or 'bluetooth' defined in your file), but it must be one parameter. 'plug:bluetooth hw:0,0' would be two parameters.

> Why we used asound.conf file.

1. Not to have to provide a specific device address directly to each command. You may set the default in `asound.conf` and omit the '-D something' option all toghether
2. To provide more sophisticated configuration for the audio output

http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Asoundrc#The_naming_of_PCM_devices

Comment: This makes sense. Circumventing the system and directly trying to grab the audio device is probably not a good idea.

Comment: Means aplay command i have to change -Dhw:0,1 to -Dbluetooth?

Comment: Whats the meaning of this hw:0,1 please can u explain me

Comment: I have already wrote that: hw:0,1 = second output of the first sound device. It can be anything, but you have the 'bluetooth' entry in your asound.conf, so you can use that instead.

Comment: @user1089679 I have updated my answer, but there was really nothing new to say. Why won't you read some documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a problem with your pulse audio setup. [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BluetoothPulseaudioTroubleshooting) is a manual for ubuntu to troubleshoot bluetooth setups including aplay. [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BluetoothHeadset) is the manual for bluetooth setup for ubuntu.

From your configuration I see that you are missing the device name, namely "aplay  -D **default** hw:0,1 -c 2 -f S16_LE abc.wav &". For my headset I have used an example [here](http://gablog.eu/online/node/80), and it works for me so far.

Comment: Means my input file is have problem?

Comment: No your input file is not the problem. Most likely problem lies in your device configuration. Can you please post your /etc/asound.conf

Comment: Please Refer Updated Question i add that file which u want to see

Comment: The device name is included in the command line – it is the 'hw:0,1' part. But this is probably not the correct one (see my answer).

Comment: i have to give "aplay -D default hw:0,1 -c 2 -f S16_LE abc.wav" or "aplay -Ddefault hw:0,1 -c 2 -f S16_LE abc.wav". There is no difference between "-Ddefault" or "-D Default"

Comment: Do not use 'hw:0,1' together with 'default'. One or the other.